# Access an objects content when creating a view from an internal function in ember.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have an ember.js Object that overrides the `create` method so I can pass some json of unknown structure to the objects content variable.

```
//model
App.Order = Ember.Object.extend({

  content: null,

  create: function(data) {
    this.set('content', data);
    return this._super();
  },

  getView: function() { 
    var self = this;
    return Ember.View.create({
      templateName: 'order-dialogue',
      classNames: ['card'],
      content: self.get('content'),
      name: 'house'
    });
  }

});
```

I have a function that generates a view for the object however I am unable to access the parent objects content. Everytime I try, `self.get('content')` returns `null`.

Quesion:

How can the view generated in the `getView` function access the parent objects content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an ember.js Object that overrides the create method so I can pass some json of unknown structure to the objects content variable.

Actually your object is not overriding the create method. It is defining a create function on the instance. So with the code you posted,

```
var order = App.Order.create({test: true}); 
console.log(order.get('content')); // undefined
```

To override the create method you need to `reopenClass` like this:

```
App.Order.reopenClass({
  create: function(data) {
    order = this._super();
    order.set('content', data);
    return order;
  }
});
```

With that in place:

```
var order = App.Order.create({test: true}); 
console.log(order.get('content')); // {"test": true}
```

> How can the view generated in the getView function access the parent objects content?

Exactly the way you coded it. There is nothing wrong with the view, it actually is returning the parent object's content. It's just that the parent object's content is not what you are expecting.

See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/idexok/2/edit) for a working example